# WooCommerce: How to hide/remove the category under the product title in the shop page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce

I would like to hide or remove the category meta from the shops page (catalogue
) which is showing right under the product title in my store. I have tried several things but nothing works.

I tried CSS:

`.product__categories {display:none!importamt;}`

and this...

```
.product_meta .sku_wrapper {
display:none!important;
}


.product_meta .posted_in {
display:none!important;
}
```

I tired this in functions too `remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );`

How can I hide the category meta?

Comment: You'll need to alter the woocommerce template that's in your theme. You'll also need to provide more code for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: can you share the URL or screenshot ?

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
.product-details .posted_in { display: none; }
```

and it worked for me

The .product_meta class you are trying to use is not on the catalogue page - it is on the product detail page.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but you might try

```
remove_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary',
              'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40);
```

in a theme (like in functions.php) or a code snippet.

The PHP solution should be slightly better because it changes the page before delivering it, rather than still serving the meta section and including some CSS instructions to not display it.

This works in WC 6.7.0. If it doesn't work, perform a search in the WooCommerce plugin for the exact lettering, `woocommerce_template_single_meta` (You can do this by loading the folder into something like Sublime Text.), and adjust accordingly. For example, if in the future, you find that it's added with `add_action( 'woocommerce_random_action_why_was_this_changed', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 50 );` you need to use `remove_action('woocommerce_random_action_why_was_this_changed', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 50);`.

**Update:** This isn't working on my own site and I don't know why.
Another thing you can do to remove the product meta section is to create a file in your theme or child theme within a `/woocommerce/single-product` path called `meta.php`, i.e:  `yourawesometheme/woocommerce/single-product/meta.php`. Give it this content:

```
<?php
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) exit;
```

This works consistently.

(I think you could leave the file completely blank, skipping the `(!defined('ABSPATH'))` part, but I'm not certain. Perhaps someone else could clarify.)